# Automatically Fill a Second Term Reference Field in a Node Based On Filled Value from a First Term Reference Field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Given the following...

- A vocabulary (let's call Vocab1) with terms that each have an added term reference field referencing a single term from another vocabulary (let's call Vocab2).
- A node that has two term reference fields, the first for a single term from Vocab1 and the second for a single term from Vocab2

would it possible to automatically fill the second term reference field from Vocab2 based on what's is filled in the first term reference field containing a term from Vocab1?

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the following modules

[Reference field option limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit)

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their widgets' available options limited by the values of other fields in the current entity.

[Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.